# How to implement piecewise numerical integration?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

Is there any way in Matlab, to shorten this function or is there any built-in function I can use instead of this? The following function works for me, but I want to exclude it from my script.

```
function p = nintegrate(x, fx)
    acc = 0;
    for i = 1:length(x)-1
            p(i) = acc;
            delta_x = x(i+1) - x(i);
            acc = acc + delta_x * fx(i);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [cumtrapz](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html), which does something similar. It used [trapezoidal integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), which is a slightly better way of doing numerical integration. Usage in your case should be (untested):

```
acc = cumtrapz(x, fx);
```

Comment: @Dyin You can use [this function from the FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19152-cumulative-cubic-integration) should you require even more accuracy.